# How to Wire Up Adjacent Isolated Scopes in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I am still learning AngularJS, and I have a bit of a conceptual question: What is the best way to wire up two adjacent, isolated scopes in AngularJS? By 'adjacent' scopes, I mean on the same level hierarchically. Consider the following page structure:

```
<div id="1" data-ng-app="angularApp">

    <div id="1A" data-ng-controller="colorCtrl as colorVm">
        <select data-ng-model="colorList" data-ng-options="color as color.name for color in colorVm.colors">
            <option>{{ color.name }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div id="1B" data-ng-controller="secondCtrl as secondVm">
        <light-color />
    </div>

    <div id="1C" data-ng-controller="thirdCtrl as thirdVm">
        <light-color />
    </div>

</div>
```

The 'light-color' directive in div#1B and div#1C needs to be able to access information from the select menu in div#1A. What is the best way to do this without assigning 'colorCtrl' to div#1 and expanding its scope? Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: sometimes what you need is not to access the information but to get notified when information changes. In this case you can use $scope.$emit() and $scope.$on() [more here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I was able to achieve this ultimately was by creating a service that interacts with all three controllers. The file now looks like this:

```
<div id="1" data-ng-app="angularApp">

    <div id="1A" data-ng-controller="colorCtrl as colorVm">
        <select data-ng-model="colorVm.colorHelper.colorPick" data-ng-options="color as color.name for color in colorVm.colors">
            <option>{{ color.name }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div id="1B" data-ng-controller="secondCtrl as secondVm">
        <light-color light-color-choice="{{ secondVm.colorHelper.colorPick.name }}" />
    </div>

    <div id="1C" data-ng-controller="thirdCtrl as thirdVm">
        <light-color light-color-choice="{{ thirdVm.colorHelper.colorPick.name }}" />
    </div>

</div>
```

And there is a service (colorHelper.service.js) that looks like this:

```
angular
    .module('angularApp')
    .service('colorHelper', function() {

        var self = this;

        self.colorPick;

    return self;
});
```

The 'colorHelper' service is fed into the arguments of each of the controllers. Each controller then has a new property that is set equal to the colorHelper service for that controller, i.e.

```
var vm = this;
vm.colorHelper = colorHelper;
```

That way, each controller is able to access the colorVm.colorHelper.colorPick ng-model via its colorHelper.colorPick.name property.

Comment: This is essentially a detailed version of the solution suggested by SteamDev.

Answer (score 2):

You could inject a common factory into each of the controllers, as a way to share data between the 3 sections.

```
function colorCtrl($scope, ..., colorFactory){
  // use colorFactory for modifying/storing color data
}

function secondCtrl($scope, ..., colorFactory){
  // use colorFactory for modifying/storing color data
}

function thirdCtrl($scope, ..., colorFactory){
  // use colorFactory for modifying/storing color data
}
```

Comment: I really like the simplicity of this answer but NG's naming conventions are really terrible....  Factory for something that's being implemented as a singleton type model/data store.  What were the NG devs thinking?

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of [scope events](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope).

```
<div id="1A" data-ng-controller="colorCtrl as colorVm">
    <select ng-change="colorVm.colorChanged(selectedColor)" data-ng-model="selectedColor" data-ng-options="color as color.name for color in colorVm.colors">
        <option>{{ color.name }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

when user picks a color from the select menu `colorVm.colorChanged()` will be called with the model value `selectedColor`. Then in the `colorCtrl`:

```
function ColorCtrl($scope, $rootScope) {
    this.colors = [...];
    this.colorChanged = function(selectedColor) {
       $rootScope.$broadcast('colorChanged', selectedColor);
    }
}
```

then in the `secondCtrl` you can do:

```
function SecondCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.$on('colorChanged', function(event, color) {
        console.log(color + ' has been selected');
    });
}
```

you can also listen to scope events in the directive `link` function:

```
...
link: function(scope) {
    scope.$on('colorChanged', function(event, color) {
        console.log(color + ' has been selected');
    });
}
...
```

Comment: I like this idea, but how would you abstract the colorChanged function to the light-color directive? In other words, trigger the light-color directive to execute where you have the line 'console.log(color + ...')?

Comment: callback function of the $scope.$on is called every time an angular event is `$emit`ed or `$broadcast`ed. much like the callback of JS event `elem.addEventListener('click', function(){})`

Answer (score 0):

Initialize an object on the parent scope. Have your `ng-model` directive connect to a property of that object. That object will be inherited by the child scopes.

The AngularJS team recommends that initializations be done in a controller. In this example I am using `ng-init` for illustration purposes. In production code, the initializations are best done in a controller.

```
<div id="1" data-ng-app="angularApp">
    <div ng-init="x='{}'"></div>
    <div id="1A" data-ng-controller="colorCtrl as colorVm">
        <select ng-model="x.colorList" 
                ng-options="color as color.name for color in colorVm.colors">
        </select>
    </div>

    <div id="1B" data-ng-controller="secondCtrl as secondVm">
        <light-color color='x.colorList'/>
    </div>

    <div id="1C" data-ng-controller="thirdCtrl as thirdVm">
        <light-color color='x.colorList'/>
    </div>

</div>
```

In a directive with isolate scope, set an attribute to the variable name, and declare that attribute with 2-way binding.

```
angular.module('angularApp').directive('lightColor', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {color: '='},
        template: '<p> lightColor color.name={{color.name}}</p>'
    }
})
```

Remember, the rule with `ng-model` is always use a dot.

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r8w75fdx/)

Comment: angular [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) discourage using ngInit for such cases.

Comment: @Arrustamyan Thank-you. I have updated the answer to include that advice.